# Servlet: send .java data to .html

Tags: servlets

I am working with a servlet, and I need to send data (from my java file) to the html file.

I need to use an appropriate overridden method (not doGet):

```
@Override
protected void doModify (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String s = request.getParamter("myText");
}
```

In the html:

```
<html>
<title>MyHtml</title>
    <body>
        <form action="MyServlet" method="MODIFY" </form>
            <tr>
                <td>Input text:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="myText" /></td>
            </tr>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would imagine my Web.xml to be relevant:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>MyFunLife</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.src.pkg.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

To reiterate, I need to send data from MyServlet.java to MyHtml.html file. And also vice versa as I am at a loss and I cannot find anything concrete online.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  You don't send data from a servlet to a .html, period (unless you mean an Ajax request from Javascript). So you need to explain what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Or better yet, now that I noticed this line `<form action="MyServlet" method="MODIFY" </form>`, you need to buy a book on webdevelopment. This is very invalid HTML.